# Should we use "ist" or "sind"?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

Why do we say, for example:

> Zustimmung und Ablehnung **ist** sehr wichtig.

Shouldn't we use **sind** because this is plural?

This has been confusing me because a teacher said it on a Youtube video.

Comment: This is a PIE feature usually refered to as ['synesis'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesis).

Comment: For learners: In case of doubt use plural

Comment: One of the most famous German songs uses exactly that grammatical structure (although arguably the plural would be somewhat more correct...) https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marmor,_Stein_und_Eisen_bricht

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both sentences are possible.

> **Zustimmung und Ablehnung** ist sehr wichtig

> **Zustimmung** und **Ablehnung** sind sehr wichtig

In the first sentence, "*Zustimmung and Ablehnung*" are regarded as a unit. This is known as ['synesis'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesis) in linguistics.

In the second sentence, they are viewed separately.

Comment: First example is joining both, hence being singular. Second example is a list, hence plural.

Comment: This subtly changes the semantics of the sentence as well - if you use singular you treat both as a unit with a unified importance, whereas the plural implies that both are each important on their own. This is not a big difference, but might lead to native speakers intuitively preferring one over the other depending on context.